# How to save BLE objects when ios app is cleared from background?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to save `BLE` instance variables such as `CBCentralManager` and `CBPeripheral`, so when the app is cleared and then relaunched, the variables can still be retrieved.

I have tried to save using `NSUserDefaults`, but I can only use object:

`NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary.`

I tried to save using Core Data, but it can only store `NSManagedObjects` and not any `NSObject`.

Is there any other way I can save `BLE` variables and still be able to retrieve them?

Comment: This isn't possible. What problem are you trying to solve with this? It is likely whatever you're trying to achieve is better addressed with Core Bluetooth State Restoration. See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html for more information, but otherwise edit your question to provide what you're actually trying to save.

Comment: All you really need to save is the identifier of the peripheral you want to connect to. When your app is relaunched you can set up your CBCentralManager, retrieve the peripheral and then open a connection. State restoration is also available for the case where your app is terminated by iOS while still connected to the peripheral or where you have a pending connection.